# How to convert 'MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal' to use?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I reference [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009642/how-do-i-bind-the-menuitem-of-a-contextmenu-of-a-datagrids-groupitem-to-the-dat), and create my `DataGrid`.

But I need to use parameter when I invoke Command.

I see that is a `MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal` type, and I don't know how to convert it.

The 'MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal' have items and it's name, how can I get it? Or, I can bind my parameter to `CommandParameter`, maybe like `SelectedItem` of `DataGrid`, because I have a `DependencyProperty` for click `Expander`.

```
public class ExpanderDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        public string SelectedExpanderName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(SelectedExpanderNameProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedExpanderNameProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedExpanderNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedExpanderName",
                typeof(string), typeof(ExpanderDataGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("",
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find the answer from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e45f8237-8aed-425e-a5b1-8fc42b6ee635/problem-with-data-template-selection?forum=wpf).

I can cast that to `CollectionViewGroup`, and got it.