# Binding ListBox.GroupStyle.ContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I have a XAML Code like so

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="Transparent">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" Foreground="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

At `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" Foreground="{Binding}"></TextBlock>`  I don't see any property `ItemCount` in `DataContext` of the window and the `ListView`. So Where does `ItemCount` came from? When I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to navigate the code Visual Studio don't find definition.

Please explain where it does come from and is it a Property often used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no Source or RelativeSource for the Binding, the source is the DataContext. Obviously the DataContexts of the window and the listview have nothing to do with it. You're binding to the DataContext of the GroupItem, not the window.

Write a simple pass-through converter:

```
public class PassThroughConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //  Set breakpoint here
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Use it in your group style template: `{Binding Converter={StaticResource PassThrough}}`. Just throw that on anything; we don't care about what it returns. We care about getting the `DataContext` in a watch window where we can poke at it.

Set that breakpoint, use the debugger, and you'll find that the runtime type of the DataContext is `MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal`.

Paste that into Google. [Look what turns up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798626/how-to-convert-ms-internal-data-collectionviewgroupinternal-to-use).

[It's a subclass of `CollectionViewGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): `Items`, `ItemCount`, `Name`, etc.

Now you can get rid of the converter, it was only an investigative tool.

It's definitely not a brush. Whatever `Foreground="{Binding}"` was meant to accomplish, you'll have to rethink it a bit.