# How to bind class properties in expander header when grouping items in listview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm grouping the items in listview as shown [here](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/). Now I want to bind some of my class properties in the expander header (group header), I'm not able to bind any properties from my class in the `<ListView.GroupStyle>` section but able to bind properties in `<ListView.View>`.

Code what I've tried:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClientAccessTool.CasesAndTasksDetailsControl"
xmlns:core="clr-namespace:ClientAccessTool.Core;assembly=ClientAccessTool.Core"
DataContext="{x:Static core:SiteListViewModel.Instance}"
>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="groupByCases2" Source="{Binding SelectedSite.CasesAndTasksList}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="CaseName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid>
 <ListView x:Name="lvCasesAndTasks" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupByCases2}}">
<ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Border  Margin="3" Width="383" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >
                                        <Expander x:Name="lvExpander"  IsExpanded="True"
                                              Style="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle3}" >
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                               <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Viewbox Height="23" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                                                        <Image  Source="/Images/RedFlag.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
                                                    </Viewbox>
                                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="250" >
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition />
                                                            <RowDefinition />
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                                        Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                                           FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                           FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                                            Foreground="Red"
                                                               Margin="5"                                                                   
                                                            />
                                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" >
                                                            <TextBlock Text="Number of tasks:"  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Foreground="Gray"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0"   
                                                                       Text="{Binding CountOfTasks}"
                                                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Foreground="Gray" >
                                                            </TextBlock>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Grid>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>                  
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
```

c# class:

```
namespace ClientAccessTool.Core
{
    public class Case 
    {
        public string SiteName { get; set; }

        public string CaseName { get; set; }

        public string CaseDescription { get; set; }

        public List<Tasks> ListOfTasks { get; set; } = new List<Tasks>();

        public string CountOfTasks => ListOfTasks.Count.ToString() ;
    }
}
```

The item source SelectedSite.CasesAndTasksList is a List of type Case. I want to bind the CountOfTasks property inside the expander header but its not working.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. Show enough code to test your solution. Include a minimal version of your class with the properties. Also, next time, please proofread your question after posting it. The text between the angle brackets was swallowed by the browser, and the question made no sense until I fixed the formatting for you.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett I've added the code. Please review.

Comment: Thanks. Let's look for binding errors in the Output pane in VS at runtime. Here's what I get: ***'CountOfTasks' property not found on 'object' ''CollectionViewGroupInternal'***. So `CollectionViewGroupInternal` is the type of the DataContext: Not one `Case`, but an object telling you about this *group* of `Case`. [One google later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798626/how-to-convert-ms-internal-data-collectionviewgroupinternal-to-use), we find that CollectionViewGroupInternal can be cast to `CollectionViewGroup`.

Comment: One more Google, and [we have the properties we can bind to.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup?view=netframework-4.8). I'm unsure of your intent in binding to `CountOfTasks`; the group header is for a group of `Case`, grouped by `CaseName`. If there's three of them, there's one `CountOfTasks` property for each. If you want the sum of the total `CountOfTasks` for all of them together, you could write a [value converter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8) that would take `Items`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I realized I did not needed the ListView grouping because the data binded in the group header will always be unique. Hence I will be using only the ListView.View and add the expander control in this section.